# youtube_player_flutter control tools freeze on IOS

Tags: youtube-player-flutter

We have an app show some youtube videos
for more than year the current version use youtube_player_flutter
in past week some **IOS** users tell us that when videos start to play the control tools was freezing
we don't know why, even though it is the same version used for many months ago

some users try to close the app and start again, other some try to shut the internet router off for some minutes
and this solutions sometimes success and other sometimes not

Note that:
When this issue happen, the video still plays and all app function still works, just player control tools only freezing

This video show the issue from a user device
https://youtube.com/shorts/qIjqYC046hM

any ideas?